# JQuery Show/Hide on Multiple Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I was able to get some simple code to work that allows me to show/hide using diffrent buttons for each action, but, I have six different divs that I want to apply this code too and only allow for one to appear at a time and if one is shown to hide it and display the new one. They will be at different places in my page.

I know that I could just write individual code for each DIV, but I'm sure there's an easier way to do it.

I tried a couple different methods, but it just gets messy. Thanks.

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".hide,.show").show();

    $('.show').click(function() {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        $(".show").hide();
    });

    $('.hide').click(function() {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        $(".show").show();
    });

});
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.slidingDiv {
    height:300px;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="show">Show</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
    Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="hide">Hide</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qKWC8/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show').click(function() { $(this).next().slideToggle(); });
    $('.hide').click(function() { $(this).parent().slideUp(); });
});​
```

Comment: How do I get it to hide one shown if they click to show another? I only want one shown at a time.

Comment: I noticed that I have to group the a tags with the div in order for this to work. Is there a way that I can list all the a tags then all the divs without it breaking?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".hide,.show").show();

    $('.show').click(function() {
        $(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $('.hide').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().slideToggle();
        $(this).parent().prev(".show").show();
    });

});
```

some [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RrMzu/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".hide, .show").show().on('click', function(e) {
        var elm = $(e.target).is('.show') ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).parent().prev('.show');
        elm.toggle().next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle()
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BxBbg/1/)